# Separate stencil with FBO (NVidia)

Tags: opengl, nvidia, fbo, stencil-buffer

I'm trying to have a FBO with separate depth and stencil buffers.
I know that NVidia GPU's historically only supported packed depth/stencil.
However I stumbled on the ARB_texture_stencil8 extension and wonder how to use it against a FBO.
This code gives gl error 1159 on glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboStencilTexture, 0):

```
    static GLuint fboId, rboDepth, rboStencil, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT;
    if (!fboColorTexture) {
        fboDepthTexture = fboId = rboDepth = rboStencil = TEXTURE_WIDTH = TEXTURE_HEIGHT = 0; // vid restart?
        glGenTextures(1, &fboColorTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboColorTexture);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }
    if (!fboDepthTexture) {
        glGenTextures(1, &fboDepthTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboDepthTexture);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }   
    if (!fboStencilTexture) {
        glGenTextures(1, &fboStencilTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboStencilTexture);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        qglTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    }
    GLuint curWidth = r_virtualResolution.GetFloat() * glConfig.vidWidth, curHeight = r_virtualResolution.GetFloat() * glConfig.vidHeight;
    if (curWidth != TEXTURE_WIDTH || curHeight != TEXTURE_HEIGHT) {
        TEXTURE_WIDTH = curWidth;
        TEXTURE_HEIGHT = curHeight;
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboColorTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB5_A1, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL); //NULL means reserve texture memory, but texels are undefined
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboDepthTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboStencilTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8, TEXTURE_WIDTH, TEXTURE_HEIGHT, 0, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_FLOAT, 0);
    }
    //-------------------------
    if (!fboId) {
        // create a framebuffer object, you need to delete them when program exits.
        glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fboId);
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboId);
        // attach a texture to FBO color attachement point
        glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboColorTexture, 0);
        // attach a renderbuffer to depth attachment point
        glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboDepthTexture, 0);
        glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboStencilTexture, 0);
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
    }
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboId);
```

Comment: "*This code gives gl error 1159 on*" There is no such error code. Either in hex or in decimal. Indeed, there is no enumeration with that value in all of OpenGL.

Comment: Maybe try my code and see WHAT error you get?

Comment: In order to try your code, it would have to be a [mcve], and it's not. It's just a fragment of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of ARB_texture_stencil8 is to permit you to use stencil-only formats as *textures*. That is, reading from them in shaders.

This does not mean that you can separate your stencil and depth buffers. The idea behind stencil-8 textures is that you would generate their data by either copying the stencil portion of a depth/stencil texture, or you would render *without* a depth buffer entirely.

So you cannot use this extension to guarantee that you can render to separate depth and stencil images. That's still hardware dependent.

Also, if you're going to use new features like ARB_texture_stencil8, you shouldn't be combining them with old EXT_framebuffer_object APIs. So stop using `glFramebufferTexture2DEXT` and start using `glFramebufferTexture`.

Comment: Well since glFramebufferTexture does not do anything differently to glFramebufferTexture2DEXT there is really no incentive to switch. It's a shame really NVidia wouldn't do such a simple thing as a separate stencil buffer.

Comment: @AntonDuzenko: "*It's a shame really NVidia wouldn't do such a simple thing as a separate stencil buffer.*" What makes you think it is "simple"? Indeed, Vulkan doesn't even allow the *possibility* of separate depth/stencil. Why? Because *nobody* supports it. So the low-level graphics API doesn't even give you the option.

Comment: Intel supports it and they're not 3d kings.